# Error Auth Laravel MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, oop, laravel-5

I had a problem like this:

> The argument 2 just passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:: the__ construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar, null given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1899 and defined.

As has been explained in the https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#troubleshooting way to fix it is twofold. Already I did as instructed but still error as above. How do I fix it?

Comment: Same issue any news?